# SUMIF, SUMIFS, OR?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a bit of a headscratch over conditional sums. Have looked around but can't quite seem to get it right.

### Here is my logic:

- If `A2` contains anything other than the letter P I want to return `=B2-C2` in `D2`.
- However, if `A2` contains the letter P I want to return `=B2-(C2/2)` in `D2`

The real application is that if a cell in `A` refers to a Group or a PGTA number then only half the students in the module would need to be housed in the room.

### What I have tried:

I have got to this stage but have evidently misconstrued something.

```
=SUM(IF(A2="<>~P",B2-C2),IF(A2="~P",B2-C2/2))
```

Perhaps I need some sort of OR use.

### Here is the data:

```
A          B          C          D
Group      Room Size  Mod Size   Difference
           34         28         6
PGTA3      15         23         0 (should be 4)
,          45         32         0 (should be 13)
GRP1       30         28         0 (should be 16)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK($A$2)), ISERROR(SEARCH("P", $A$2))), B2-(C2/2), B2-C2)
```

The `SEARCH` function returns index of a substring in a text (reference to text of cell A2).
If it's not found, it returns `#VALUE!` error.

With this in mind, we just tell what we want to do with a simple `IF(Condition, True, False)` formula

Comment: Thanks very much Rawrplus! However, I found the answer (after several gins in fact :D) and I was off track with my explanation I think. What I did achieve was =IF(OR(A2="",A2="~P"), B2-C2, B2-(C2/2)). I'm going to try your answer and see what that does anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it is unclear from your question. Does it really work though? Like yeah, checking for blank might work, but `A2 = "~P"` will return `TRUE` only if the cell contains value `~P` and nothing else. Is that really what you want to do? My formula checks if the letter `P` is contained anywhere in your cell

Comment: Check my edited answer, this contains a check for empty cell as well

Comment: Yes, it does seem to work; if anything other than P is in the cell, just subtract, if P appears anywhere in a cell, divide first number by 2 then subtract. Just getting to grips with this site (some kind soul edited my question to what appears to be the standard) so apologies for any clumsiness. However, I'll still be looking at your answer as it looks more beautiful even if if does do the same thing. :)

Comment: @LebHeidenstrøm please mark this as your chosen answer if it solved your problem, and if you have time, [edit] your question to more clearly express your problem as discussed here in the comments. That way this solution will also be helpful to future readers! :)